Reversing a 3D Transformation
Background
I'm trying to do the following:

Create a 4x4 transformation matrix of an object that reflects its 3D transformations
Determine the coordinates of the four vertices of the object post-transformation
Modify the 4x4 transformation matrix so it may be used to "undo" the transformations
Determine the coordinates of the four vertices of the object pre-transformation

In other words, I have the coordinates of an object after its transformation, and I'm trying to get the coordinates of the object before its transformation was applied. These coordinates will always reflect a box with four vertices pre-transformation. Post-transformation, it may be another shape that isn't strictly a square box.
I'm running into problems at #4.

Example
Suppose I have a square with sides of 100px, centered in a screen that is 1000px by 1000px. The origin (x, y) coordinates (0, 0) are at the top-left corner of the screen, while the bottom-right corner of the screen would be (1000, 1000).
The coordinates of the top-left, top-right, bottom-left, and bottom-right corners of the square, and its center, are:
TL: (450, 450)
TR: (550, 450)
BL: (450, 550)
BR: (550, 550)
 C: (500, 500)

Now, suppose the square is rotated 45 degrees clockwise around its center, so it resembles a diamond. The center coordinates are the same, but the coordinates of its vertices have changed:
TL: (500.00, 429.29)
TR: (570.71, 500.00)
BL: (429.29, 500.00)
BR: (500.00, 570.71)
 C: (500.00, 500.00)

Then, suppose the square is translated -50px to the left before rotation. The coordinates of its center and the coordinates of what used to be its top-left, top-right, bottom-left, and bottom-right corners are:
TL: (450.00, 429.29)
TR: (520.71, 500.00)
BL: (379.29, 500.00)
BR: (450.00, 570.71)
 C: (450.00, 500.00)

This is the process through #2.
The current problem is that I need to be able to calculate these final coordinates, but I'm not sure how. I know what they should be in this case, since I've stepped through the transformations individually, but I need a way to derive these using the transformation matrices, for any given transformation. There's more information on this below.

Details and Documentation
This section details how the final 4x4 matrix is calculated, and provides some documentation.
transform-origin
Matrix math for the web
A CSS transformation matrix is originally calculated by following these steps:

The transformation matrix is computed from the transform,
transform-origin, translate, rotate, scale, and offset properties as
follows:

Start with the identity matrix.

Translate by the computed X, Y, and Z values of transform-origin.

Translate by the computed X, Y, and Z values of translate.

Rotate by the computed  about the specified axis of rotate.

Scale by the computed X, Y, and Z values of scale.

Translate and rotate by the transform specified by offset.

Multiply by each of the transform functions in transform from left to
right.

Translate by the negated computed X, Y and Z values of
transform-origin.



The matrix representing the total transformation is:
$$Transformation = \begin{pmatrix}0.7071&-0.7071&0&450\\0.7071&0.7071&0&-207.11\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$

Attempting to Reverse the Transformation
Now, I need to take the 4x4 transformation matrix and the final coordinates of the object's vertices, and use those to recreate the original coordinates. In practice, I won't know what the original coordinates were.
My method of applying the transformation to the coordinates is to multiply the 4x4 matrix with each of the four points. Each point is represented as a 4x1 matrix in the following format:
$$Point = \begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}$$
The first two values are the (x, y) coordinates of one of the post-transformation vertices. The last two values represent the z-axis and perspective, which use default values.
The matrix representing the reversed total transformation is:
$$ReversedTransformation = \begin{pmatrix}0.7071&0.7071&0&-171.75\\-0.7071&0.7071&0&464.64\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$
This matrix, once applied to the vertices of the post-transformation object, should return the vertices of the pre-transformation object.
However, when applied to the points as described above, it returns these coordinates:
TL: (400, 400)
TR: (600, 400)
BL: (400, 600)
BR: (600, 600)
 C: (500, 500)

A square with the correct center, but with sides of 200px instead of 100px.
Thanks to helpful feedback so far, I know the matrices up to this point are correct. The problem is that the points to which I'm applying the reversed total transformation matrix are not correct.
Here's a visual that illustrates the problem:

I have the coordinates of the vertices of the red box, but I need the coordinates of the vertices of the black box. Once I obtain the coordinates of the vertices of the black box, applying the reversed transformation matrix to those points should result in the coordinates of the box before it was transformed.
In this case, it's simple enough to see that the coordinates are adjusted by half the height/width, but it won't always be so simple, so I'm trying to find a general mathematical solution using what I have.
Is there a way to obtain the coordinates of the black box, for any given transformation, using the following data?

The 4x4 matrix representing the total transformation
The individual 4x4 matrices used to obtain the total transformation matrix
The 4x4 matrix representing the reversed total transformation
The coordinates of box that bounds the post-transformation element (the red box above)

If there's a way to do it, but more information that these four items would be needed, please let me know since I may be able to derive it. For example, I may also have access to the height and width of the object before it was transformed.

Welcome to MSE! <> I haven't carefully read your post, but in the hope it's helpful: If we let $x$ denote the pre-transformation coordinates of a general point and $y$ the post-transformation coordinates, your transformation is $y = Ax + b$ for some orthogonal $3\times3$ matrix (the upper-left block of your $4\times4$ matrix) and some column $b$ (the first three components of the fourth column). The inverse is $x = A^{-1}(y - b) = A^{-1}y - A^{-1}b$. Finally, because $A$ is orthogonal, $A^{-1} = A^t$, the transpose.

@AndrewD.Hwang Thanks! Do you think calculating the points using that method is more appropriate than inversing the entire matrices? I'm not familiar enough to know which is more suitable.

I can't speak to more appropriate since you may have constraints on methods, or other reasons to work with affine transformations as $4\times4$ matrices. The scheme I mention is how I'd proceed, because it looks easier. :) <> Incidentally, my claim about "$A^{-1} = A^t$ because $A$ is orthogonal" is not quite right. Your transformation involves scaling. If this means uniform scaling my comment is easily fixed; if the scaling might be non-uniform, please disregard the final sentence.

Got it! Yeah, there could definitely be non-uniform scaling.

There are a couple issues I see here: one is that you should be doing your origin transforms with $(500, 500)$ as your target new origin, since that's the point you're rotating about, and secondly at step 7 in your list of steps you've multiplied the wrong way around. (All new transformations have to go on the left, as they did in steps one through six, so the transform back also goes on the left.) You can maybe see that something's gone wrong there at your final result---you're claiming a total transformation matrix with a first row of $(0.7071, -0.7171, 0, -50)$, and so that would take any point where the $x$- and $y$-coordinate are the same (such as your top left point that's supposed to be originally $(450,450)$) to an $x$-coordinate of $-50$, which is ... bad.
Without some details it's hard to see what exactly you've done to try to calculate numerically, but the idea of "inverse matrices in the opposite order" is sound; I think you should have found your original total transformation matrix as
$$T = \begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&500\\0&1&0&500\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}0.7071&-0.7071&0&-50\\0.7071&0.7071&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&-500\\0&1&0&-500\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}.
$$
The two on the outsides are already the inverses of each other so they'll stay fixed for this purpose, and so you can find the inverse of that middle matrix and re-multiply everything out to get $T^{-1}$.

Thanks! You're right about the transform-origin - I knew something was wrong with it, but was too far in the weeds to realize it. You're also right about the multiplication order. I had it the right way originally, but started doubting it when writing the question. I made these changes, and the result is closer now - the square is centered, but still twice the size as before.

So a couple possibilities: if you're building your inverses, remember that now the 50px translation should be before the rotation, since originally you did it afterwards.  If you just use a calculator or pencil-and-paper to invert that middle matrix in my expression for $T$ above you'll get there automatically; if you're building it from the pieces make sure you get that order right. (The inverse of that middle part of $T$ would have a fourth column that starts with roughly $(35.35, -35.35)$, or that's what you should get by translating +50px then doing the rotation.)

And for completeness/to check your work, my expression for $T^{-1}$ would have the negative sign in the second row, first column of the square-of-square-root-of-one-halves in the top left, and then in the fourth column a translate of $(-171.76, 464.64)$.

Thanks again! These comments were helpful, and now I'm confident that matrices are all being correctly calculated. The problem that was causing the double-width is in the final step - applying the matrix to the points. I don't have the correct points yet. I updated the question with additional information, in case you have any ideas.

@pez Oh. You only have the bounding box of the result, not the actual result?  Well, you stated at the top you know it's a box, so the end result of the translation should be at least a parallelogram with a vertex on each side of your bounding box. I would think if you un-transformed that red bounding box you'd still have to have a corner of the original box on each edge, but to pick a particular box out of all the possibilities would take extra knowledge (height/width might be enough if you knew for sure it was "nicely positioned", i.e. had horizontal/vertical edges).

Sorry, that was a mistake I meant to edit out earlier. I meant to say it will always begin as a box pre-transformation. Post-transformation it could be some other shape.
